# Is Ackermann's set theory minus class comprehension equal to ZF?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

[Ackermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory) in 1956 proposed an axiomatic set theory.

Reinhardt proved that [Ackermann's set theory equals ZF](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484370900112)

It's clear that Zermelo set theory can be interpreted in Ackermann's set theory minus class comprehension.

> Is Ackermann's set theory minus class comprehension also equal to ZF?

In other words: did Reinhardt's proof made an essential use of the class comprehension schema in proving the equivalence between Ackermann's set theory and ZF?

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer? I also wonder whether [extensionality](https://mathoverflow.net/a/168307/74578) and [regularity](https://mathoverflow.net/a/54328/74578) are necessary to interpret ZFC. Can we keep just the axiom schema of set comprehension, the axiom of elements, and the axiom of subsets?

Comment: I don't know the answer yet, although the below presented answer seem to say that it is equivalent, so no need for class comprehension, but yet I'm not sure, regularity is generally not needed for the interpretation of ZFC, and I think extensionality not needed as well because the class of all co-extensional sets to some set, is a set. If class comprhension is not needed, then we only really need two axioms one of completness (any element or subset of a set ,is a set) and set comprehension. But I'm not sure really.

Comment: IF class comprehension is not needed, then this would mean that we only need two axiom schemata that of "class comprehension" and "set construction" presented in linked question below: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334208/whats-the-exact-consistency-strength-of-this-elegant-axiom-system-for-classes-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be the $V$ from $A$. It is clear $V$ satisfies exstensionality, seperation, and regularity. Pairing follows from reflection ($x=a\lor x=b$). Inductively, we can prove each $n\in V$, and so we have $\omega\in V$. If $X\in V$, then $\cup X\subseteq V$. Then define $\phi(x)\leftrightarrow \exists y(y\in X\land x\in y)$. By reflection $\cup X=\{x|\phi(x)\}$, and so  $\cup X\in V$. A similar argument goes for powerset. For replacement, let $F=\{(x,y)|\phi(x,y)\}$ be a function. Then $F(X)\subseteq V$ (By definition). Then we can find some $V_\alpha$ that reflects $\phi(x,y)$ relative to $V$, and $x\in F(X)\leftrightarrow \exists y(y\in X\land\phi(x,y)^{V_\alpha})$, and so $F(X)\in V$. Therefore $V\vDash \phi$ for each axiom $\phi$ of $ZFC$. Now suppose an axiom of $ZFC\,\phi$, satisfies $\phi\vdash\psi$. Then every model of $\phi$ satisfies $\psi$, and so $V\vDash\psi$.

**Proof the $V$ satisfies the reflection theorem:** Note that the statement $x\in V_\alpha$ is $\Delta_1$, and so $V_\alpha^V=V_\alpha$. In addition, the mapping $\phi(x,\alpha)\leftrightarrow rank(x)<\alpha$ is $\Delta_1$, and so $\phi(x,\alpha)^V\leftrightarrow\phi(x,\alpha)$. Then for any $\alpha\in V$, $V_\alpha=\{x|rank(x)<\alpha\}$, and so $V\vDash Replacement\,for\,\alpha\mapsto V_\alpha$. As a consequence, for any $C\subseteq V$,  the set $\hat C=\{x\in C|\forall y\in C(rank(x)\leq  rank(y))\}$ is in $V$.

Let $H(u_0...u_n)=\hat C$ and $C=\{x|\phi^V(x_0...x_n)\}$. Then, for any set $M_0\in V$, define a sequence starting at $M_0$ with $M_{i+1}=M_i\cup(\cup\{H(u_0...u_n)|u_0...u_n\in M_i\})$. The function $F^V:{i\mapsto V_{ran(M_i)+1}}$ can be defined inductively, and it is easy to see that if $F(i)\in V$, $F(i+1)\in V$. Then $D=\cup \{H(u_0...u_n)|u_0...u_n\in\cup F(\omega)\}$ is in $V$. Then $x\in F(i)\leftrightarrow (i=0\land x\in M_0)\lor (\exists j(j+1=i\land x\in F(i)\cup ((D'\restriction F(i))(F(i))))$, where $D'$ is the union of the class of all sets such that each $x\in D'$ is $\hat C$ for some $C$ and $\cup D'=D$. What I mean by $(D'\restriction F(i))(F(i))$, is really $(G\restriction F(i))(F(i))$, where $G=\{(x,u_0...u_n)|x=H(u_0...u_n)\land u_0...u_n\in F(i)\}$. And so $V_\alpha=\cup F(\omega)$ is in $V$ and $V_\alpha\vDash\phi\leftrightarrow V\vDash\phi$ (By induction on formula complexity).

Comment: I didn't get the argument for Replacement. for example your $F(X)$ seems to be a subclass of the domain of $F$ it consists of elements of $dom(F)$ that have their images among their elements, I don't see why this $F(X)$ class should be a subset of $V$ for an arbitrary function $F$? Its not that clear.

Comment: I think I made a typo on the second to last line. Is it clearer now?

Comment: what do you mean by $F(X) \subseteq V$ (by definition), you have an arbitrary class $X$ and $F(X) $is the image of $X$ under function $F$, why you think that images must be subsets of $V$? for example let $X$ be $\{V\}$ and let $F$ be the equality function, clearly $F(X)=X=\{V\}$ which is not a subset of $V$ and it is not an element of $V$.

Comment: What we are trying to prove is first that $V\vDash ZFC$. To prove this we have to show that every definable function $F: V\rightarrow V$ has its image in $V$. By the definition of a function, its image is a subset of $V$ (You can't map using replacement, say $n\mapsto \kappa_n$, where $\kappa_n$ is the $n$th worldly cardinal, and therefore prove $Con(ZFC)$).

Comment: If you show that for every $X \in V$, any definable function $F:X \to V$ implies that $F(X) \in V$, then yes this would definitely interpret Replacement over $V$! BUT the problem is how to prove that? Ackermann minus comprehension can only prove that statement for the kind of functions that are definable after formulae that do not have $V$ occurring in them and only when all their parameters are elements of $V$ also. It cannot show it for all kinds of formulas, in particular it cannot show it for bounded by $V$ formulas, which are the wanted formulas for a proof of replacement!

Comment: The kind of formulas we want to use do not have the symbol $V$. If we want to prove $V\vDash ZFC$, we show that it satisfies Replacement for every formula with **parameters in $V$**. Those are exactly the kind of formulas Ackermann set theory allows us to use.

Comment: the matter is a little bit subtle, I agree that it gives the appearance of having a proof by reflection, the problem is that barring $V$ from occurrence in the formulas of reflection will bar us from proving replacement for bounded by $V$ formulas, and to prove that $V$ is a model of ZFC, then all quantifiers in the statement of replacement must be really bounded by $V$. In order to achieve this you need some kind of definable sets in $V$ that do not use $V$, that bound the quantifiers and have the same effect of bounding by $V$.

Comment: Yes, I was once thinking like that, but its not true, in order for $V$ to be a model of ZFC, you need all quantifiers in that statement to be bounded by $V$, this includes the formula of replacement, its not enough to just require that the parameters in $V$, and that the matrix of the formula doesn't use $V$, this would not make $V$ be the domain of a model of ZFC, so it would NOT provide the needed interpretation.

Comment: You are correct. However, wouldn't $V$ at least satisfy Replacement for $\alpha\mapsto V_\alpha$, as $V$ is transitive and $x= V_\alpha$ is $\Pi_1$. Then it satisfies the reflection theorem and so we can find $\phi(x,y)^V\leftrightarrow \phi(x,y)^{V_\alpha}$, and so we can use $V_\alpha$ as a parameter?

Comment: generally speaking you are on the right track now. But I generally feel that proving this won't be easy, I think that what Reinhardt's proof is about.

Comment: I have added some more details.

Comment: You CANNOT prove Replacement in this theory simply because the parent theory (i.e. Ackermann's set theory) cannot prove replacement! This theory is just a fragment of Ackermann's set theory, so it cannot prove Replacement. However we may be able to "interpret" replacement. Notice that Ackermann's set theory cannot prove that $V$ is a model of ZFC, so this theory also cannot prove that. What can be done really is to check if Reinhardt proof did use class comprehension axioms in an essential way, in order to check if class comprehension is redundant or not. Cheers

Comment: It is a theorem of Ackermann's that $V$ is not a model of $ZFC$. The reason is because ZFC is equivalent to Ackermann's over set sentences of Ackermann's, now if Ackermann's prove that $V\models ZFC$ then there would be a set sentence theorem of Ackermann's that "there exists of a model of ZFC", which simply means that ZFC would prove its own consistency, which is false per Godel's incompleteness arguments.

Comment: Just because $A$ does not prove $V\vDash ZFC$, doesn't mean $A$ does not prove $V\vDash\phi$ for any specific instance of $ZFC\,\phi$. For any specific instance of $ZFC\,\phi$, $ZFC\vdash \phi$ and so $\phi^V$.

Comment: Yes, true, but that doesn't mean that you proved that $V\models ZFC$ which is what you wrote in your answer [ you wrote: therefore $V\models ZFC$]. You can prove matters piecemeal as you said and this would "interpret" ZFC but not prove it. The difference is subtle, but its there! You need to correct your answer.

Comment: You are correct. I have adjusted my answer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: you have a typo at $x \in C | \forall y \in z ...$ I think $z$ is a typo, it should be $x$.

Comment: It is $\forall y\in C$. Is the answer sufficient now?

Comment: what's the purpose of defining the set $\{x\in C|\forall y\in C(rank(x)\leq  rank(y))\}$? this is the subset of $C$ that is the set of all elements of $C$ of the least rank. What's the relevance of this set to the proof.

Comment: also what's the relevance of mentioning $\Delta_1$ point?, the most important is absence of the $V$ symbol. I'm still not sure of the proof. But I'll have a closer look at it and examine it further!

Comment: The standard proof of the Reflection Theorem uses the set of all elements of $C$ of the least rank (See Set Theory, Chapter 12). $\Delta_1$ formulas are absolute for transitive sets so $V_\alpha^V=V_\alpha$, and that lets verify Replacement for $\alpha\leftrightarrow V_\alpha$.

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: There is some point! You say *inductively* we can prove $n \in V$. I personally don't think this is possible, induction doesn't work for formulas having $V$ in them, the proof that all naturals are in $V$ is not by induction. The usual proof is by defining a natural as an element of every set that has the empty set as an element that is closed under adjunction, of course this would be a set because $V$ is such a set and so every natural must be an element of $V$. So one needs to be careful from freely applying induction, because its not guaranteed for every formula.

Comment: What I mean is that $0\in V$, and $n+1=\{x|x\in n\lor x=n\}$, which is definable and so in $V$. And as $n+1^V=n+1$, $\omega\subseteq V$ and morover it is definable without using the symbol $V$, and $\omega^V=\omega$ and so $V\vDash Infinity$.

Comment: even if $0 \in V$ and for every natural $n \in V$ we have $n+1 \in V$ still that doesn't mean that all naturals are in $V$, you cannot use the predicate $`` \in V"$ in induction, because simply its forbidden in the reflection axiom. For example you can suppose that there is a natural [defined as a finite von Neumann ordinal] that is not in $V$, without reaching into any clear inconsistency by that argument alone. However, if you define natural as an element of the intersection class of all inductive classes, then yes here you can prove that every natural is in $V$.

Comment: You prove by induction $\omega\subseteq V$. You don't define $\omega$ by induction.

Comment: the point is that you cannot prove $\omega \subseteq V$ by induction. Simply induction for $V$ is not a theorem of this theory because you cannot use $V$. You cannot prove by induction that every natural an element of $V$. However $\omega \subseteq V$ is indeed a theorem of this theory, no doubt, but this is not proved by induction.

Comment: You can use proofs using any symbol in Ackermann set theory. You can just only use $L(\in,=)$ in reflection. But the language of $A$ is $L(\in,=,V)$.

Comment: induction in this theory only work for properties definable after a formula that doesn't use the symbol $V$. You can easily suppose the existence of a natural $n \not \in V$, how you'll prove in this theory that this is contradictory. Ordinarily we take the set of all ordinals smaller than $n$ that doesn't fulfill $P$ as a proof of violation of well foundedness of $n$, but to do that you need to use reflection and since $P$ here is the predicate of being an element of $V$, this is forbidden from being used. You see!

Comment: try to prove the induction theorem for all formulas in this theory, you'll see you cannot. However you can prove induction and transfinite induction for formulas not using $V$ (from parameters in $V$). I'm raising this point just to make sure that non of your additional arguments are using induction over formulas using $V$, which would render them ineffective.

Comment: I see, you are right. I was immediately assuming that $\omega\cup V$ was a set. I see now the flaw.

Comment: do you mean $\omega \cap V$ is a set, which is, since it is $\omega$ itself. The proof that $\omega$ is a set i.e. it is an element of $V$ is to define natural as an element of every class that has the empty set among its elements and that is closed under adjunction. Now clearly $V$ is one of those classes, so this mean that all naturals must be in $V$. Its more of a trick really. Clearly you cannot assume that $\omega \cup V$ is a set, since this is $V$ itself! and $V$ is a class but it is not a set, since a set is defined as what is an element of $V$ and we have $V \not \in V$

Comment: Yes, I meant $\omega\cap V$.

Comment: I'm not understanding your answer. You need to explicitly say if the answer is YES or NO. Is there a real need for the class comprehension axiom of Ackermann or not?