# What's the exact consistency strength of this axiom system for classes and sets?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

*Notation:* Let $\phi$ be any formula in $\mathsf{FOL}({=},{\in}, W)$; let $\varphi$ be any formula in $\mathsf{FOL}({=},{\in})$ having $x$ free, and whose parameters are among $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$.

Note: “$W$” is a primitive constant symbol.

$\DeclareMathOperator\elm{elm}$Define: $\elm(y)\iff \exists z (y \in z)$, where “$\elm$” is short for “… is an element”.

**Axioms:**

1. **Extensionality:** $\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$.
2. **Class Comprehension:** $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \elm(y) \land\phi(y))$; where $x$ doesn't occur in formula $\phi(y)$.
3. **Set Comprehension:**
   $x_1,\dotsc,x_n \in W \to \\ [ \forall x (\varphi(x) \to x \subseteq W) \leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi(x) \to x \in W)]$.
4. **Foundation:** $x \neq \emptyset \to \exists y \in x (y \cap x = \emptyset)$.
5. **Choice** over all classes.

The basic two axioms of this theory are the two comprehension schemes, all the rest of axioms are indeed interpretable from them. $W$ stands for the class of all *sets*, that's why the predicate $\elm$ is used here instead of the usual denotation of it as $\operatorname{set}$ in Morse–Kelley class theory.

In my opinion, this kind of axiomatization is *ideal*, I think it's one of the most elegant ones. There is no substantial dispute over axioms 1 and 4. Schema 2 is the most natural principle about classes. Schema 3 technically sums up all of what's in standard set theory in a neat manner. Axiom 5 is a stretch of choice to all classes, which is done in versions of Morse–Kelley and NBG, so it's encountered in systems that are considered fairly standard about classes and sets. All axioms are clean and fairly natural.

> Question: What's the *exact* consistency strength of this theory?

Comment: Ideal? That seems to be like Pocket set theory more than a ZF/NBG/KM variant... Where's the power set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think powerset falls out of set and class comprehension. Roughly: set comprehension gives that any subclass of a set is a set; class comprehension gives that the class of all subsets of a set exists; and set comprehension says that that class is a set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the idea is to interpret $ZFC$ over $W$ and not over $V$ the class of all elements (which Noah calls as $E$).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I personally think this theory is STRONGER than ZFC\NBG\MK. it is much stronger than what it looks.

Comment: *(Turning my misinterpretation into a comment)*: Note that if $W$ were a *relation* symbol, this theory would be quite weak - in particular, consistent relative to PA. Let $M$ be a nonstandard model of PA, $\alpha$ a nonstandard $Ackermann(M)$-ordinal, consider the the expansion of $(V_{\alpha+1})^{Ackermann(M)}$ by interpreting $W$ as the well-founded part of $Ackermann(M)$, and note that set comprehension follows from overspill. Having $W$ an actual object changes things: e.g. $W$ satisfies Infinity since it's the smallest adjunction-closed set.

Comment: Have you proved that $W$ is a model of ZFC in your theory? Or do you believe you can  prove this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can construct a model of your theory from ZFC with an inaccessible.  If $\kappa$ is inaccessible, you let the universe be $V_{\kappa+1}$ and let $W$ be $V_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\kappa$ such that any ordinal less than $\kappa$ definable in $V_{\kappa+1}$ with parameters from $V_\alpha$ is less than $\alpha$.  (You can prove such an $\alpha$ exists using inaccessibility of $\kappa$.)

Comment: These axioms are weird in that they imply the existence of many elements that are not sets (since $W$ needs to not be definable with parameters from $W$), but say very little about such elements.  For instance, if you have any model and a class $C$ in the model which is not an element, it seems you can get a new model by just making $C$ an element: i.e., for every class $D$ that you had, add a new class $D\cup\{C\}$.  (Although I suppose if $C$ is not definable with parameters from $W$, this might somehow mess up set comprehension.)

Comment: @WillSawin I believe it can prove that. For instance this theory interprets Ackermann's, so it interpret ZFC. However Ackermann's set theory doesn't prove its universe of sets being a model of ZFC, so that interpretation alone is not enough for proving $W \models ZFC$. Yet this theory is stronger than Ackermann's, so I tend to think it can prove $W \models ZFC$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @EricWofsey, this is an aspect that it shares with Ackermann's. Both theories have many classes that they don't speak about a lot. But this theory speaks of those sets more than do Ackermann's do, since class comprehension here is more expressive.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I'm not sure this theory is appropriately complete (I mean with respect to the intuition): can you show that extensionality holds in $W$? (That is, that if $x,y$ are distinct elements of $W$, then there is some $z\in W$ with $z\in x\Delta y$.) This seems like something you'd want ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber, yes this follows from transitivity of $W$, and Extensionality of course. Actually I think that even if I remove Extensionality, still it would be interpretable in this system. But this is another story.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, the "bi-conditional" in set comprehension grant transitivity of $W$, but even if we weaken it to "implication" still we can get to interpret $ZFC$ over the class of all Hereditarily $\in W$ sets.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, take $\varphi$ to be $x=x_1$, and substitute it in set comprehension.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Ah, d'oy.

Comment: Who is this axiom system due to?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, to my trivial knowledge I've first presented here as a question. I don't know if it was on table before this attempt. I've presented before a similar axiomatization to FOM but with implication instead of the biconditional in set comprehension, and it was only the two schemas.

Comment: Do you recall which schema or FOM post you’re referring to in your last comment?

Comment: Also, does dropping extensionality, foundation, and/or choice retain the consistency strength (as they do for ZFC)?

Comment: @user76284 yep!

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Do you have a link to that FOM thread?

Comment: @user76284, sorry for late reply, this is it: https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2019-March/021437.html

Comment: Do you have a typo in class comprenhesion? Don't you intend $\phi(y)$ rather than $\phi(x)$?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, Yes! It's a typo. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Class comprehension gives a class $V$ of all elements.  If we add a sixth axiom $W=V$, does this calibrate your axiom system with respect to NBG and KM?

Comment: @PaceNielsen, No! $W=V$ is inconsistent, because $W \in V$ is a theorem, so this leads to $W \in W$ and this is paradoxical.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar How does one prove that $W$ is an element (of any class, let alone $V$)?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @PaceNielsen, I can prove this indpendent of the question of $W \in V$. This theory proves the reflection axiom of Ackermann's (over $W$), so any formula in the language of set theory from parameters in $W$ that only hold of elements of $W$ would define an element of $W$. Take the formula $x \text{ is an ordinal that have a successor }$, now if $W=V$, then the class of all ordinals that have successors would be an element of $W$, a contradiction. Also we can get to prove $W \in V$ also, I think $W=\bigcup_\alpha W_{\alpha \in W}$ can be proved from foundation, and thus we'll have $W \in V$.

Comment: @PaceNielsen, by my last line I mean we can also take the formula "$x$ is a stage of the cumulative hierarchy that has a successor stage", and the same argument would prove that $W \in V$.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your comments, if you have two infinite theories $T$ and $T'$, if $T'$ consists of $T$ plus the schema $M\vDash T$ for some constant $M$, without alternate assumptions (Such as the existence of a truth predicate) $T'\nvdash Con(T)$. This is why $ZFC+V_\kappa\prec V\nvdash V_\kappa\vDash ZFC$.

As for your actual theory, if $M\vDash ZFC$, then there is some $(N,V_\kappa^N)$ such that $V_\kappa^N\prec N$. I claim for any formula $\phi(x_0...x_n)\leftrightarrow\phi^{N_0}(x_0...x_n)$, where $N_0=\text{def}(N)$, if $\{(x_0...x_n)|\phi(x_0...x_n)\}\subseteq V_\kappa^N$, then $\{(x_0...x_n)|\phi(x_0...x_n)\}\in V_\kappa^N$ and $\{(x_0...x_n)|\phi(x_0...x_n)\}$ is definable in $V_\kappa^N$, the only tricky case being the existential quantifier.

Note that $\{(x_0...x_n)|\exists x(\phi(x,x_0...x_n))\}=\text{ran}(\{(x,x_0...x_n)|\phi(x,x_0...x_n)\})$. Now if $\{(x,x_0...x_n)|\phi(x,x_0...x_n)\})$ is definable in $V_\kappa^N$, then $\text{ran}(\{(x,x_0...x_n)|\phi(x,x_0...x_n)\})\in V_\kappa^N$. Furthermore, $\{(x_0...x_n)|\exists x(\phi(x,x_0...x_n))\}$ is definable as $\text{ran}\{(x_0...x_n)|\phi(x,x_0...x_n)\}$. The rest is trivial.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to check that, for each axiom of ZFC, your theory proves that the set $W$ with the relation $\in$ satisfies each axiom of ZFC. This implies the consistency strength of your theory is at least the consistency strength of ZFC.

I succeeded for every axiom, but failed for the axiom of replacement. My successful arguments should be helpful for attempts to lower bound the consistency strength, and my failed one might be helpful for attempts to upper bound it.

---

First lets prove some lemmas:

A. $ (x \in W) \rightarrow (x \subseteq W)$. This follows from axiom 3, taking $\varphi$ to be $(x=x_1)$, getting $(x \in W) \implies  ( (x \subseteq W) \leftrightarrow (x\in W))$ which is equivalent.

B. $((x_1 \in W) \land (x \subseteq x_1)) \rightarrow (x_1 \in W)$. This follows from axiom 3, taking $\varphi$ to be $(x_1 \subseteq x)$.

Now using axiom 1 and lemma A, $(W, \in)$ satisfies the axiom of extensionality.

Using axiom 4 and lemma A, $(W, \in)$ satisfies the axiom of foundation.

Now the axiom schema of specification, axiom of pairing, axiom of union, and axiom of power set we prove by essentially the same strategy. They all imply that a set satisfying some conditions (depending on some free variables) must exist. To prove these, we must first use axiom 2 to show that the class exists, then axiom 3 to prove it is an element of $W$. In particular, we can use axiom 3 in the form that if the predicate $\varphi$ defines a unique $x$, then that $x$ is a subset of $W$ if and only if it is an element of $W$.

For the axiom scheme of specification, in the first step we use that elements of a fixed set $z$ must be elements, and the second step we use lemma B.

For the axiom of pairing, we use that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in $W$, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are elements, so $\{x_1,x_2\}$ is class, and then $\{x_1,x_2\} \in W$ by applying axiom 3 to the predicate $x =\{x_1,x_2\}$.

For the axiom of union, we use that if $w \in y$ and $y \in \mathcal x_1$ then $w$ is an element, so $\{ w | \exists y : w \in y \land y\in x_1\}$ is class. Then we apply axiom 3 to the predicate $x =\{ w | \exists y : w \in y \land y\in x_1\}$, using two applications of lemma A to verify the hypothesis.

For the axiom of power set, we use lemma B to verify that every subset of $x_1$ is an element of $W$ and hence is an element, so the power set of $x_1$ is a class, and then lemma A to verify that this is a subset of $W$ and thus to be able to apply axiom 3.

For the axiom of infinity, following Noah Schweber's suggestion, we first observe that the empty set is contained in $W$ and, for all $y$ in $W$, the successor of $y$ is in $W$, by applying axiom 3. We then note that the set of $z$ such that $z$ is contained in all classes containing the empty set and closed under succession exists by property 2, since all such $z$ are elements. Finally this set is contained in $W$, because it is uniquely defined and only a subset of $W$.

The argument for the axiom of choice is similar, except that given a set $x_1$ of sets, we must use axiom 5 to construct a choice function, and then apply axiom 3 to the predicate `` $x$ is a choice function of $x_1$" which from lemma A and the axiom of pairing (to construct ordered pairs) satisfies the hypothesis.

---

For the axiom scheme of replacement, we start with a predicate $\phi$ and assume we have a set $A \in W$ such that for all $x \in A$, there is a unique $y \in W$ satisfying $\phi$. We can then define the class consisting of all $y \in W$ that satisfy $\phi$ for some $x \in A$, using class comprehension. However, this definition requires the symbol $W$ - if we drop it, $\phi$ might no longer be a function, and the image of $\phi$ might contain elements that don't lie in $W$ - so I don't see how to get the axiom of replacement.

However, there should be no problem with using the axiom of replacement to construct ordinals, as we can always take a function that produces the smallest ordinal satisfying some condition, so maybe there is a way around this.

Comment: This system interprets easily Ackermann's set theory, its easy to prove ackermann's reflection axiom. It is known that Ackermann interprets ZFC (Reinhardt). So it must interpret ZFC.